# Ionic 4 Infinite Scroll

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I am trying to load dynamic data using infinite scroll, but the event does not fire when I get to the bottom page.

```xml
         <ion-content (ionScroll)="scroll($event)" [scrollEvents]="true">
           <ion-refresher slot="fixed" pullFactor="0.5" pullMin="100" 
          pullMax="200">
                  <ion-refresher-content></ion-refresher-content>
                </ion-refresher>
       //Data


        <ion-infinite-scroll threshold="100px" (ionInfinite)="loadData($event)" 
        [disabled]="runtimes <= 0" *ngIf="!noRecord" >
              <ion-infinite-scroll-content
              loadingSpinner="bubbles"
              loadingText="Loading more data...">
            </ion-infinite-scroll-content>
            </ion-infinite-scroll>


          <ion-refresher slot="fixed" (ionRefresh)="doRefresh($event)">
               <ion-refresher-content
                pullingIcon="arrow-dropdown"
                pullingText="Pull to refresh"

                refreshingText="Refreshing...">
              </ion-refresher-content>
            </ion-refresher>
       </ion-content>
```

The Ionic Infinite Scroll event does not fire in the TS file. I have reached the bottom of the  page but there was no animation.

```js
        @ViewChild(IonInfiniteScroll) infiniteScroll: IonInfiniteScroll;
        @ViewChild(IonContent) content: IonContent;


      //Requesting Data
      loadReport() {
         return new Promise(resolve => {
           this.postPvdr.postData(body, 'proses-api.php').subscribe(data => {
             for (let report of data.result) {
              this.income.push(report);

              }
            resolve(true);
             });
          });
        }
```

This is the event for the infinite Scroll

```js
         loadData(event) {
        //To limit the Number of Loading 
       this.runtimes = this.runtimes - 1;

        if (this.runtimes < 0) {
          this.noRecord = true;
        }
        setTimeout(() => {

          this.loadReport();

          event.target.complete();
        }, 2000);
      }
```

Any answer is welcome.

Comment: In the `ts` file are you making sure that you have a `@ViewChild()` on the InfiniteScroll?

Comment: Yes .@ViewChild(IonInfiniteScroll) infiniteScroll: IonInfiniteScroll;

Comment: Could you please add your full template and controller?

Comment: I think the problem is the if statement. Looking at the [docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/infinite-scroll) there is a function that disables it automatically so I think with your if statement you might be disabling it from the start

Comment: Maybe your issue with ``[disabled]="runtimes <= 0" *ngIf="!noRecord"``

Comment: Even after removing the disabled and ngIf it still did not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

downgrading "@ionic/angular"  to "^4.5.0" works fine.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue of the last version of Ionic (4.6.0 I believe). Current solution is to downgrade to 4.5.0 where it's still working.

For more information please follow this issue: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/18632